# drupal 7 how to fire ajax callback when text field changes

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I am trying to add an ajax callback to be fired when a text input field is changed, but can't figure out how to do it.  I have tried adding an ajax event to the field in the form_alter hook (which worked well for a select field), but its not firing:

```
my_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    form['my_text_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'my_text_field_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'my-field-wrapper',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'event' => 'change'
   );
}
```

The callback is as simple as it gets:

```
function my_text_field_callback($form, &$form_state) {
    return $form['my_text_field'];
}
```

I have also tried keypress keyup events as well, but can't get the callback to fire.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? AFAIK the change event only fires when a textfield loses focus. Try the input or keyup events.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this link can help you : https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms-in-drupal-7

- Changes to the form must only be made in the form builder function (ajax_example_autocheckboxes() in the example here), or validation will fail. The callback function must not alter the form or any other state.
- About Ajax callbacks and #default_value: When Ajax replaces form elements on the page, the form field values are not automatically populated with #default_value. However, there are other ways to set default values when using Ajax callbacks. See these links for further discussion/hints and example code: Form API: default value does not change and Default_value not working for Radio Buttons in Ajax Callback.
- It is possible to replace any HTML on the page, not just a form element. This is just a matter of providing a wrapper ID.
- You can easily replace the entire form if that is easiest. Just add a #prefix and #suffix to the entire form array, then set that as the #ajax['wrapper']. (This will allow you to change multiple form elements via a single ajax call.) The only reason not to do this is that the process is faster if less information is transferred.
- Keep in mind that the $form you're dealing with in your callback function has already been sent through all the form processing functions (but hasn't yet been sent to drupal_render()). So while adjusting, say, the markup of an element is straightforward:

  $elements['some_element']['#markup'] = 'New markup.';

  return $elements;
- Changing a value that has already been converted into the #attributes
  property means digging deeper into the $form array, as well as also
  changing that element's corresponding property.

  // You need to do both

  $elements['some_element']['#disabled'] = TRUE;

  $elements['some_element']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';

  return $elements;

Comment: Thanks for such a complete breakdown. Lots of helpful info, but in this case I am trying to create the callback in the form builder function not in the callback. Or am I missing something?

Comment: maybe try another event type  ? change type is more efficient with select or checkboxes , try another for textfield like keyup ?